# ADB Cannot Find Android Device

Tags: eclipse, adb, android

Yes I know this problem has been brought up many times, and I have looked through many of the possible solutions over this past afternoon. I'm running Windows8 and have an LG Lucid 3 Device. Android Version 4.4.2

-Usb Debugging is turned on.

-I have tried adb start-server / adb kill-server

-I have tried setting the connection to "PTP mode"

-I have tried that universal google usb thing

-I've tried the the installer for my device specifically.

One thing that I've noticed that is different from other people's problems is that when I go to device manager, it shows my device under "portable devices" instead of "other devices".

"Universal driver":https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH

Also, when I installed the universal driver, it didn't show up under my list of available drivers to install for the device under device manager.

Has anyone had a similar problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: There were a usb connection option "Internet" in LG phones. Select that and try. It worked for me in some LG devices

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. You are indeed a saint.

Comment: Glad to know :) I posted it as an answer. Please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a usb connection option "Internet" in LG phones. Select that and try. It worked for me in some LG devices